# jquery ajax добавление в массив

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, не могу разобраться с тем, как получить последнее добавленное в массив значение...

```
$('#dev').on('click', '.btn', function() {
if (i <= 2) {
  i++;
  j++;

  var mac_i = $('#mac' + (i - 1)).val();
  var ip_i = $('#sel' + (i - 1) + ' option:selected').val();
  console.log(mac_i, ip_i);

  $.ajax({
    url: '<%=ajaxResourceUrl%>',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    data: {
      mac: mac_i,
      ip: ip_i
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $('#resultValid').html(response);

      if (ip_i === 'NewIp') {
        Ip.push(response.match(ValidIpAddressRegex)[0]);
      }

      $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td> <input type="text" name="mac" id="mac' + i + '" required placeholder="Enter Devices MAC." class="mac" /><//td>' +
        '<td> <select id="sel' + i + '"><//select> <//td>' +
        '<td> <button class="btn" name="newIp" id="btn' + i + '" type="button">reg.<//button> <//td><//tr>');

      for (k = 0; k < (Ip.length); k++) {
        $('#sel' + i).append('<option>' + Ip[k] + '<//option>');
      }
      $('#sel' + i).append('<option>NewIp<//option>');
      $('#btn' + (i - 1)).hide();
      console.log("success");
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error.");
    }
  });
} else {
  alert("Permit only " + (i + 1) + " records!");
}
});
});
```

...но последнее, добавленное в массив, значение получаю только после нажатия следующей кнопки, либо при полном обновление странницы.

Подскажите куда посмотреть, новичок в этом деле)

Comment: Не могу вникнуть в лапшу. Можно **минимально воспроизводимый** пример? Что на входе, что ожидается и что получается.

Comment: Вот тут можно почитать про [mcve]

Comment: Я не могу понять о каком массиве идёт речь? Также, что это за теги у вас `<//tag>`? Это что-то для jquery? Последний элемент массива можно получить так: `arr[arr.length-1]`